# How can I group logs by a certain portion of the log string in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, opensearch

I am doing an analysis on my logs in ElasticSearch and trying to figure out which 10 users hit a certain endpoint the most.

My log format is:

```
API request: [GET] /api/v1/person from user: 4fe5e06a-6h33-4661-a9ab-ee8d82523ca7
```

I'd like a grouping similar to the following:

```
user_id, requests_made
4fe5e06a-6h33-4661-a9ab-ee8d82523ca7, 59
6fe4e06a-6h35-4231-a1al-sbfe0018mco0, 52
.....
```

How I can figure out how many identical logs exist per unique UserID **if I don't know the UserID's** ahead of time? (ie. I don't know which UserID's will have the most logs, I need that insight generated)

I'm searching via API request:

```
GET _search
{
  "aggs": {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned how you are indexing data to Elasticsearch and considering that you can not change mapping or reindex hence giving below approach.

You can use [runtime field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-examples.html) from the Elasticsearch to achieve your desire output.

lets consider you have `message` field which is storing your log then you can use below query for generating output:

```json
POST 75838359/_search
{
  "fields": [
    "userid"
  ], 
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "userid": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": """
        String userid=grok('%{GREEDYDATA:msg}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:userid}').extract(doc["message.keyword"].value)?.userid;
        if (userid != null) emit(userid); 
      """
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "userdetails": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userid",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above Query will return below result:

```json
"hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "75838359",
        "_id": "ufRCI4cBYGx8nLsbCifL",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "message": "API request: [GET] /api/v1/person from user: 4fe5e06a-6h33-4661-a9ab-ee8d82523ca7"
        },
        "fields": {
          "userid": [
            "4fe5e06a-6h33-4661-a9ab-ee8d82523ca7"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "userdetails": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "4fe5e06a-6h33-4661-a9ab-ee8d82523ca7",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I will suggest to create userid field at index time using grok pattern and use that field directly for aggregation if you are able to reindex your data.